# Is toy metal gun allowed on a Turkish Airways?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, turkish-airlines, firearms

I bought a toy metal gun from Romania. This product made by Spain. It look like a real gun. Are toy metal guns allowed on Turkish Airways?

Comment: Please don't do this. Seriously, you need to ask this? Put in your checked luggage.

Comment: @MikeHarris It's more complicated than that. There may be special declarations needed to prevent security or customs from [getting upset](https://youtu.be/duZGFC9RRLs?t=21m26s) when they x-ray your bag. In the US when you transport real firearms, you have to sign a form, and TSA comes and does a special inspection.

Comment: Note: in many countries is prohibited to carry toy metal gun (or any thing that seems a toy). Consider also your safety: carry it anywhere increases sensibly the risk of being shot down by police and by criminals.

Answer (score 6):

Among [Turkish Airlines](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/any-questions/restrictions/) restrictions, it notes that toy guns cannot be carried on you, or in cabin baggage, but may be carried in checked baggage.

Answer (score 6):

A toy metal gun will not be allowed in the cabin on *any* airline.

Comment: Many countries do not even allow them in when transported in hold luggage.

Comment: Funny, since you can check-in _real_ metal guns on [many](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/baggage/firearms-and-ammunition.jsp) [airlines](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/before-your-trip/special-items.html).

Comment: @user71659 because there are a procedure for that, which involves removing the amo and crew will be informed. but for toy guns, they are just "toys" and implementing a specific policy for that is not practical, and crew will not be notified and it they will think it's real gun..

Comment: @NeanDerThal Please explain why it's "not practical" to implement a policy for toy guns. You tell the security agent that it's a toy gun, they inspect it, and they tell the X-ray operator to ignore it. Would work on other apparently prohibited items, e.g. empty camping gas cylinders. What's not practical about it? Saves everybody time and effort.

Comment: @user71659, it's not practical because the security authorities cannot warn and advise everyone out in the world (including airline crew and law enforcement in other jurisdictions and every passenger on the flight) who might see the toy and assume it's real.

Comment: @David This answer says no airline will carry a toy gun. This is provably false. No airline will allow a realistic toy gun in the cabin, which incurs the problems you describe.

Comment: user71659, you're right. I've amended the answer to limit it to carry-on.